# Debugging crash in CoreGraphics/MapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, mapkit

I am getting an intermittent crash when my application runs on an iPhone. All the crashes are identical and involve MKMapView Overlays (MKCircleViews) in some way.

From a typical iPhone 4s crash report:

Report Header:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         EL-GPS-01 [1021]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/61288E15-74B5-45B9-99A9-E0B58C767816/EL-GPS-01.app/EL-GPS-01
Identifier:      EL-GPS-01
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-22 15:59:41.065 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  6
```

And the crashed thread:

```
Thread 6 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 6 Crashed:
0 ??? 0000000000 0 + 0
1 CoreGraphics 0x319a87c2 0x31967000 + 268226
2 CoreGraphics 0x3199a9e6 0x31967000 + 211430
3 MapKit 0x37ec3564 0x37e6f000 + 345444
4 MapKit 0x37ec3652 0x37e6f000 + 345682
5 MapKit 0x37ecc0a4 0x37e6f000 + 381092
6 QuartzCore 0x3341be18 0x33410000 + 48664
7 QuartzCore 0x334d77e0 0x33410000 + 817120
8 QuartzCore 0x3346af24 0x33410000 + 372516
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x3797e892 0x3797b000 + 14482
10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x360e31ca 0x360d9000 + 41418
11 libsystem_c.dylib 0x360e30a0 0x360d9000 + 41120
```

When the application crashes whilst my iPhone is connected to my laptop I get the following in my output panel:

```
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
```

The debugger gives me nothing at all, and the Issue navigator shows a crashed thread with nothing on the stack.

There is a very simple project highlighting the problem here:

https://github.com/1ndivisible/MKOverlayBug

[git@github.com:1ndivisible/MKOverlayBug.git](http://git@github.com:1ndivisible/MKOverlayBug.git)

I'm not sure how to approach this. Is there any information here that I can use? It seems the crash is originating deep in the framework.

Comment: Did it worked on simulator ?For me it's not getting crash on the same.But yes, when I try to pinch it ... it gets ,So is this the issue you are facing on ?

Comment: I’m hitting this crash in my own application in 5.0 on the simulator and device. If it’s any consolation, it appears fixed in iOS 5.1.

Comment: A link-answer below points [to this resource](https://cocoadev.com/DebuggingAutorelease.html); it may be deleted in the future, so I'll add this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known bug. Apple have acknowledged it. There is currently no fix. All you can do is compound your graphics into fewer annotations. I have found  <=3 annotations is safe.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I submitted a TSI to Apple and they told me submit it as a bug.Another developer did the same.He asked if there was a work around and they said 'not at this time'. This was maybe 6 weeks ago. I suggest you look at Apple's breadcrumb example and combine your graphics into 3 or less annotations. I have spent a long time trying to beat this bug and that was the solution I ended up having to take. If you PM me I'd be happy to send you some code, though it's really just derived from Apple's breadcrumb example which you can find below:

Comment: Breadcrumb link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: do you know what other conditions are known to be causing the bug to manifest? because I am not having any problems with >25 annotations and individual maps for each of the 50 US states.

Comment: No. I could never isolate it. It's always triggered by interaction or animation but it was always very unpredictable.  I found that with any more than 3 overlays the bug would eventually emerge. Try setting up some simulated location data and let it run for a while with the map panning to keep your position in the center. I expect you will find the crash will occur. What exactly is your situation. When are you experiencing the crash?

Comment: I don't get a crash.  See my answer above for why I think it is crashing.  Based on the code you posted on github, I can see why you are having problems with crashes, running in the simulator on a simulated route brought my MacBook pro to its knees.

Comment: @timthetoolman This is actually a very old post from me. My current code is entirely rewritten from the bottom up. It is another poster who has started the bounty, not me. I am just relating what I learned subsequent to my original question in the hope it will help him and save him from the days I spent trying to track down the bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are running out of memory or you are running up against a bug in MapKit.  But in it's defense it doesn't seem like you are using the overlays and MK views correctly and are overburdening the MKMapView with keeping track of so many potential overlays.  Case in point.  When the following method you are adding 50 overlay's to the current location:

```
-(void)addOverlays
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
       MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:currentLocation.coordinate radius:50];
       [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
    }
}
```

over time this can add up to a large number of overlays that the MKMapView needs to keep track of and MKViews that it potentially has to display at once.  With your example code and the iPhone simulator's location simulator the simple bike ride route accumulated over 1800 MKCircle and MKCircleViews in the MKMapView.

Here are a couple things to keep in mind:

1. Don't add so many overlays per location.  1 is sufficient.  50 is overkill.
2. One MKCircle should be sufficient for each location. Not sure why
   you are choosing to keep track of and draw so many circles at each
   location.
3. Try to be more efficient about handing overlays over to the MapView.
   Only give it the overlays it needs for the part of the map it is
   showing.  Check out the WWDC2011 video "Session 111 - Visualizing
   Information Geographically with MapKit" which shows how to optimize
   this or the HazardMap sample code.

You could do something along these lines:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
    // Add it to an NSArray that you use to keep track of ALL the overlays
    [self.allOverlays addObject: MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:currentLocation.coordinate radius:50]];

     // Now add it to the mapView if it is in the current region

     // code to check to see if currentLocation is within the current map region

     if (overlayIsInMapRegion){
         [mapView addOverlay: circle];
     } 
}
```

Then whenever the region changes, calculate the overlays that are needed when the MapView calls the delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

get the region from the mapView and create an array of overlays that are located in that region. Something along the lines of:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    // Create a method that takes the region and calculates which overlays it contains
    NSArray *newOverlays=[self overlaysForRegion: mapView.region fromAllOverlays: self.allOverlays];
    if ([newOverlays count]>0){
         [mapView removeOverlays];
         [mapView addOverlays: newOverlays];
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Tim

Answer (score 1):

> KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000 Crashed Thread: 6

This tells you that something tried to de-reference a null pointer.  You probably released an annotation, or some data belonging to an annotation when you shouldn't have.  Run the app under the debugger with zombies enabled, and see what you get.

Also, run the static analyzer over your project, and correct *all* of the issues it finds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Static Analyser shows no issues and Instruments shows no leakage. Enabling Zombies doesn't help and reports nothing before or as a result of the crash. I have stripped the code back to the bare bones (so all it does is add overlays to an MKMapView) and I am still getting the same problem. An intermittent crash that might occur after 10 overlays are added or might occur after 200.

Comment: I would start with figuring out why calls to MapKit are happening on thread 6 and not the main thread...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it may be trying to execute code at address 0 (rather than access data from there.)   If you get it to crash on the debugger again,  check the value in the PC register.  If the value is zero, then you are executing at zero, not fetching data.

If this is the case, it could be that your stack is being corrupted during execution.  Some buffer overflow of a local variable could put zero into the stack frame's return address.